# apply() to every column of every dataframe of an ExcelFile, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an xlsx file with *multiple* worksheets.

I read it in & separate the worksheets into dataframes:

```
xls=pd.ExcelFile('path/to/multisheet_excelfile.xlsx')
dfs={sheet: pd.read_excel(xls,sheet) for i, sheet in enumerate(xls.sheet_names)}
```

I iterate thorugh the dataframes, & then iterate though the rows, to apply [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
for df in dfs.values():
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda name:
                                            # apply some function here, let's say:
                                            re.sub("[\[].*?[\]]", "", repr(name)))
```

**Is there a better way to do this, possibly not involving a double for loop?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it without loops because `pandas` creates `DataFrame` from `sheet`. But you can do it in 1 loop:

```
# {'sheet_name1': df1, 'sheet_name2': df2, ...}
dfs = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=pd.ExcelFile('file_path').sheet_names)  # type: dict
dfs = {
    sheet_name: df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub("[\[].*?[\]]", "", repr(x))
    for sheet_name, df in dfs.items()
}
```